# Oracle how do I find out the max number of concurrent sessions?

Tags: oracle

I am creating an application with ASP.Net and I wanted to figure out how many users concurrently connect to our database. (the existing app is a Windows app and there is no way to get this information).

I am not looking for live data but what the max # of users had been at any point. If there is a way to specify a date range than that would be preferred.

Thank you

Right now we are using 11.x but will migrate to 12 (or higher)

Answer (score 5):

The below returns the maximum number of concurrent sessions in the instance since it started, example:

```
SQL> select max_utilization from v$resource_limit where resource_name = 'sessions';

MAX_UTILIZATION
---------------
             94
```

Comment: It should be noted that this answer and the other one give different results, although both are supposedly showing the max sessions since instance startup (according to the Oracle docs). Anyone know why?

Comment: @PaulRussell `v$license` includes user sessions only. `v$resource_limit` includes sessions of background processes too.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the V$License view to check out the max sessions since the last startup.

```
SQL> select sessions_current,sessions_highwater From v$license;

SESSIONS_CURRENT SESSIONS_HIGHWATER
---------------- ------------------
              29                163
```